# Sending Fax through .NET/C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, windows, fax

How do I go about sending fax in .NET?  We have a fax server through which we need to fax documents to clients.  Since we have a fax server, I don't imagine that I have to configure a fax modem on my machine, right? It would just go through the fax server?

Are there any good free (or cheap) Fax APIs out there? IN my research I've come across FAXCOMEXLib, FaxMan, and Windows Fax Service, but the documentation seems limited, so I am hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Your fax server should provide a way to send faxes to it via email, FTP, or some other network protocol. What software is it running?

Comment: Good question, I've forwarded that to our network guy.  So, if it allows us to send faxes via email, I'd just have to email the doc to the fax server?

Comment: Yes. One application that I worked on would email to the fax server a message with a specially-formatted subject line, which included the fax number to use, and one or more PDF attachments to be faxed. The details, however, will depend on the fax server you have.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks, I'm hoping for something similar on my end...will have to wait and find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, .NET doesn't have anything built in to directly support sending faxes via a fax server. Absent that, you'd probably want to use the COM interface to the fax server. Basically, you create a FaxServer object and invoke its Connect method to connect to the fax server. You then invoke the FaxServer's CreateDoc method to create a fax document object. The FaxDoc object has a (huge) number of properties to specify more about the recipient and document than any sane person would imagine, but the two main ones are the FileName and FaxNumber. Once you've set those (along with any others you want) you invoke its Send method to send that document to that fax number.

I last played with this a few years ago, so I'm probably skipping a few things. Mostly I remember that it seemed strange that the FaxServer created a blank FaxDoc that you filled in and then asked to send itself, and that there was a *lot* of documentation covering "stuff" that initially seemed like it would be necessary, but turned out to be completely irrelevant, at least for what I was doing (and in retrospect, probably usually would be).

Comment: Thanks.  I actually just tried this (using the FaxComLib) and I get this error "hresult e_fail has been returned from a call to a COM component".  After Googling it, it seems like this error is thrown when connecting to a fax server instead of a modem configured on the local machine.

Comment: @Prabhu: I was using it with a FAX server, not a local FAX MODEM, so I'm sure it's possible, or at least was. If memory serves, this was an XP client and Win2K3 server. I'm trying to remember -- it vaguely seems like there were actually a couple of different FAX components, only one of which worked. Doing a quick glance on MSDN indicates that there's an "Extended COM Object", which may be the thing to use.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your budget, you may consider a fax to e-mail service instead. Many services have a .NET-compatible API, and reasonable rates.

This is likely to be considerably easier (and therefore, cheaper) than actually interacting with a fax server.

Comment: Actually this is for a company, and for privacy reasons this is not going to be possible. So, it's really that tough to interact with a fax server?  All I want to do is to send some pdfs to the fax server instead of to the printer.

Comment: Also, international faxes are likely to be considerably cheaper and more reliable through such a service.

Comment: I am not necessarily saying it is difficult; I don't know to do this without some research, but it's what I'd do. I'll take your word for it on privacy reasons as I can't know the laws that affect you, but I know many UK businesses that use fax APIs for this purposes, even with confidential documents.

Comment: Thanks...I'll have to consider this if it comes to it.

Comment: Of course, if privacy *really* is an issue, then sending stuff unencrypted over the public telephone network might not be your best option. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use any 3rd party API like interfax, then you have to use Faxman or FAXCOMEXLib. But from this year [www.data-tech.com](http://www.data-tech.com) is not responding which provide faxman or faxman jr SDK for sending fax. faxman jr product is not working on windows 10. although they are announce that it will work on windows 10 PC, but it is not working.

http://www.data-tech.com/blog/post/FaxMan-SDK-Version-5-Upgrade-Available.aspx

I am not sure but may be data-tech just stop their service, because last time I email them multiple time but they are not responding anything. So you can use faxcomlib and this is a very simple to send fax.

Please check link for a sample using FAXCOMEXLib.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/C-Send-Fax-using-fax-Modem-357aca81/

Comment: FAXCOMEXLib is not exist

Comment: @MahmodAbuJehad You need to add a reference in the project to c:\windows\syswow64\fxscomex.dll.  Once this is added, you should see a reference to faxcomexlib in the project's list of references.